# SQL Server: Dynamic pivot with headers to include column name and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to use dynamic pivot and need help on converting rows to columns

The table looks like:

```
ID   expense  revenue date
1    43       45      12-31-2012   
1    32       32      01-01-2013 
3    64       56      01-31-2013
4    31       32      02-31-2013
```

and I need for reporting purposes like

```
ID  expense12-31-2012  expense01-01-2013 expense01-31-2013 revenue12-31-2013
1   43                 32                
3                                        64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get both the `expense` and `revenue` columns as headers with the `date`, I would recommend applying both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions.

The UNPIVOT will convert the expense and revenue columns into rows that you can append the date to.  Once the date is added to the column names, then you can apply the PIVOT function.

The UNPIVOT code will be:

```
select id, 
  col+'_'+convert(varchar(10), date, 110) new_col, 
  value
from yt
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (expense, revenue)
) un
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30421/7). This produces a result:

```
| ID |            NEW_COL | VALUE |
-----------------------------------
|  1 | expense_12-31-2012 |    43 |
|  1 | revenue_12-31-2012 |    45 |
|  2 | expense_01-01-2013 |    32 |
```

As you can see the expense/revenue columns are now rows with a `new_col` that has been created by concatenating the date to the end.  This `new_col` is then used in the PIVOT:

```
select id,
  [expense_12-31-2012], [revenue_12-31-2012],
  [expense_01-01-2013], [revenue_01-01-2013],
  [expense_01-31-2013], [revenue_01-31-2013],
  [expense_03-03-2013], [revenue_03-03-2013]
from
(
  select id, 
    col+'_'+convert(varchar(10), date, 110) new_col, 
    value
  from yt
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (expense, revenue)
  ) un
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for new_col in ([expense_12-31-2012], [revenue_12-31-2012],
                  [expense_01-01-2013], [revenue_01-01-2013],
                  [expense_01-31-2013], [revenue_01-31-2013],
                  [expense_03-03-2013], [revenue_03-03-2013])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30421/6).

The above version will work great if you have a known number of dates to turn into columns but if you have an unknown number of dates, then you will want to use dynamic SQL to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col+'_'+convert(varchar(10), yt.date, 110)) 
                    from yt
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'expense' col union all
                      select 'revenue'
                    ) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id,' + @cols + ' 
            from
            (
              select id, 
                col+''_''+convert(varchar(10), date, 110) new_col, 
                value
              from yt
              unpivot
              (
                value
                for col in (expense, revenue)
              ) un
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for new_col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30421/8). Both queries generate the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bluefeet!! Just curious to know if the value column can take other values such as date too. I have other columns such as date which I want to do the same pivot ie date_12-31-2012 but it is giving me an error that it conflicts with the type of other columns in the UNPIVOT list

Comment: @ShivMady You will have to perform a cast/convert on any data that is not the same datatype. So you might have to use a subquery prior to the unpivot to convert the data to the same type.

Comment: Bluefeet:could you please let me know where to fit in the sub-query? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @ShivMady see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30421/9. I added a subquery with a comment where you do the conversions

Comment: hi Bluefeet, the pivot is working wonderfully well but was told that I now need the data in the following format: ID Expenses_2012 Revenue_2012 Expense_2011 Revenue_2011 1 2 3 Expense_2010 Revenue_2010. There are particular columns such as YTDdate_03292013 which contain 20121231 and if yes it should populate it in 2012 and if 2011 it should populate it in 2011 but if it is 20120930 which is not end of year it should populate in another set of columns labeled partial year and should have provision for putting arnd 5 partial dates. Do you think I should use the pivoted code and parse it?

Comment: @ShivMady My suggestion would be to post a new question with the details of the new problem.